# Loading the player independently from the tilemap

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm working on a top-down game in PyGame and I just implemented loading different maps. Only issue is, the player is loaded within the tilemap, so if a player is loaded on the left of the map, goes to an exit on the right of the map bringing them to the second map, they will once again render on the left of the map. But when the player goes back to the original map, they will still be loaded in on the left of the map instead of on the right of the map where they came from.

Here's how the tilemaps are stored:

```
class tilemap01():

def __init__(self):
    
    self.mapdata = [
        '1111111111111111111111111111111111111111', 
        '1111111111111111111111111111111111111111',
        '1111111111111111111111111111111111111111', 
        '1000000000000000000000000000000000000001', 
        '1000000000000000000000000000000000000001', 
        '1000000000000000000000000000000000000001', 
        '1000000000000000000000000000000R00000001', 
        '10P0000000000000000000000000000000000001', 
        '1000000000000000000000000000000000000001', 
        '1000000000000000000000000000000000000001', 
        '1000000000000000000000000000000000000001', 
        '100000000000000000000000000000000000000T',
        '100000000000000000R000000H0000000000000T', 
        '100000000000000000000000000000000000000T', 
        '1000000000000000000000000000000000000001', 
        '1000000000000000000000000000000000000001', 
        '1000000000000000000000000000000000000001', 
        '1000000000000000000000000000000000000001', 
        '1000000000000000000000000000000R00000001', 
        '1000000000000000000000000000000000000001',
        '1000000000000000000000000000000000000001', 
        '1000000000000000000000000000000000000001', 
        '1111111111111111111111111111111111111111', 
        ]

    self.links = {
    (39, 11): 'tilemap02',
    (39, 12): 'tilemap02',
    (39, 13): 'tilemap02'
    }
```

self.links determines which tiles in the current map lead to which other similarly stored map.

Here is how the tilemaps are actually loaded in:

```
def setTilemap(self, tilemap):
    tilemap = getattr(leveldata, tilemap)
    self.tilemap = tilemap()
    self.new()

def TileCreate(self):

    for i, row in enumerate(self.tilemap.mapdata):
        for j, column in enumerate(row):
            grass(self, j, i)
            if column == '1':
                block(self, j, i)
            if column == 'P':
                self.player = Player(self, j, i)
            if column == 'R':
                rover(self, j, i)
            if column == 'T':
                map_change_trigger(self, j, i)
            if column == 'H':
                house(self, j, i)
```

self.tilemap is defined in the initialization of the Game class. leveldata is the name of the file that stores all my tilemaps, which I have imported.

Here's the player class initialization function:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, game, x, y):

    self.game = game
    self._layer = p_layer
    self.groups = self.game.all_sprites
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
    pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 32) #frequency, size, channels, buffersize

    self.x = x * TileSize
    self.y = y * TileSize
    self.x_change = 0
    self.y_change = 0

    self.facing = 'down'
    self.an_loop = 0
    self.footstep_timer = 0

    self.width = TileSize
    self.height = TileSize

    self.image = self.game.playerspritesheet.get_sprite(0, 0, 32, 32)

    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = self.x
    self.rect.y = self.y
```

Not sure if this is relevant, but here's player movement:

```
    def movement(self):
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if self.footstep_timer > 0:
        self.footstep_timer -= 1

    if self.footstep_timer == 0:
        self.footstep_timer = 20

    if keys[pygame.K_w]:

        self.y_change -= PlayerVel
        self.facing = 'up'

        if self.footstep_timer == 20:
            random.choice(self.footsteps).play()

    if keys[pygame.K_a]:

        self.x_change -= PlayerVel
        self.facing = 'left'

        if self.footstep_timer == 20:
            random.choice(self.footsteps).play()

    if keys[pygame.K_s]:

        self.y_change += PlayerVel
        self.facing = 'down'

        if self.footstep_timer == 20:
            random.choice(self.footsteps).play()

    if keys[pygame.K_d]:

        self.x_change += PlayerVel
        self.facing = 'right'

        if self.footstep_timer == 20:
            random.choice(self.footsteps).play()
```

And here's what's probably a pretty important part: a function that determines player collision with map change triggers, which load new maps when collided with:

```
def mct_collision(self):
    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.game.triggers, False)
    if hits:
        key = (int(hits[0].rect.left/TileSize), int(hits[0].rect.top/TileSize))
        if key in self.game.tilemap.links:
            self.game.setTilemap(self.game.tilemap.links[key])
        else:
            print('bad collision')
```

The print is to notify me when one of the keys of the dictionary in the leveldata is off and stops the game from crashing if that happens.

That's all the relevant code. What I'm trying to do here is load the player independently from the tilemap so that it's not statically loaded in and store the player's x and y values to load them into the correct coordinates every time a new map is loaded (and since maps in my game are like in the original Zelda, new maps are loaded in very frequently.)

Answer (score 1):

The player (and any other dynamic objects) are not part of the map. The player  is on the map. Beneath the player is grass (or something similar). The player has only a position (coordinate) that defines his position on the map.
Remove the player from the map, but add an attribute that stores the player's starting position. When you draw the scene, you draw the map first, and then draw the player on the map.